# Inno installer - How to retrieve environment variables during install?

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to assign an environment variable to a variable on runtime? And then edit it?
So for instance, a clients computer has a program installed at c:\Company\CoolProgram and that folder location is in a variable called %InstallLocation%. So if you echo %InstallLocation% you will get c:\Company\CoolProgram

I want to install a plugin into c:\Company. So that CoolProgram and PlugIn will sit next to each other in c:\Company. I read that this could be done by defining a variable and assigning %installLocation% to it, then then trimming off \CoolProgram from the variable. So for example:

#define PluginLocation GetEnv('InstallLocation')

#define PluginLocation2 StringChange(PluginLocation, "\CoolProgram ", "")

So, PluginLocation2 = c:\Company, and that's good. Except this is going on during compile time. The build machines don't have this environment variable, plus not all clients are going to have the same installed location. Therefore %InstallLocation% is actually just empty, and therefore PluginLocation and PluginLocation2 are empty.

So I tried moving the variable definitions down into [Setup], hoping the environment variables would be looked up during runtime on the client. That didnt seem to work. I also tried into [Files] since I have files to move into the new folder, but [Files] appears to be during compile as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
procedure Test ()  ;
begin
  MsgBox(ExtractFileDir(ExpandConstant( '{app}' ) ) , mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO ) ;      
end;
```

is what You are looking for.

`ExpandConstant( '{app}' )` will return location where application is installed.

And: `ExtractFileDir` will get `c:\Company` from `c:\Company\CoolProgram`.

Comment: Thanks. Its not exactly what I needed, but with the help from another website, I discovered that I could call code from inside [setup]. And if thats the case, I could just make a function that gets the environment variable, and runs ExtractFileDir on it. So for example:

function GetInstallFolder(Param: String): String;
var
 InstallLocation: string;
begin
 InstallLocation := ExtractFileDir(GetEnv('InstallLocation'));
 Result := (InstallLocation);
end;

And then inside Setup:
DefaultDirName={code:GetInstallFolder}

Comment: After a test on several systems, I discovered that the environment variable on some clients have an \ at the end. So, some are c:\Company\CoolProgram and others are c:\Company\CoolProgram\. For the ones with the extra backslash, apparently I can do a second ExpandConstant. But that goes back too far for the clients that dont have a \ at the end of the folder. So now somehow I need to account for both.

Comment: check this

function RemoveBackslash(const S: String): String;